# Not able to cache image using method downloadImageWithURL in SDWebImageManager

Tags: ios, swift, caching, uiimageview, sdwebimage

I am using the code given below to download the image using `downloadImageWithURL` method and to assign the image to a `UIImageView` and cache the same image using `SDImageCache().storeImage`, but i am not able to cache the image. Am i missing anything?

Here is my code:

```
SDWebImageManager.sharedManager().downloadImageWithURL(profileImageURL,
options: SDWebImageOptions.HighPriority, 
progress: { (min:Int, max:Int) -> Void in
            }) 
{ (image:UIImage!, error:NSError!, cacheType:SDImageCacheType, finished:Bool, url:NSURL!) -> Void in
    if (image != nil)
    {
       self.userProfilePic.image = image
       SDImageCache.sharedImageCache().storeImage(image, forKey: "userProfilePicImage", toDisk: true)

    }
}
```

Comment: you working on which version of Swift ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SDWebImage` has a Method `sd_setImageWithURL` which will download the image and save it to Cache also, you don't need to manually save that image on Cache

Try below code it will solve your problem

```
self.userProfilePic.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg")!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png")!)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the github page, there's a category specifically for UIImageView. Look for `Using UIImageView+WebCache category with UITableView` on https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage as they give an example.

This both sets the image, caches it and uses a placeholder image whilst the image is fetching.